# How to add value to gridview

Tags: android

I need add data to gridview table, when button is click. My code:

```
    String[] data = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"};
    GridView gvMain;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smena); 
          adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.tvText, data);
                gvMain = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
                gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
           Button but1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                     ButtonOn (1);
                }
            });
    }

    public void ButtonOn (int Art){
        adapter.add("1");
        gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

When I Click button, my application has stoped unexpectedly.

Comment: By the way, in your `ButtonOn` method, instead of re-setting the adapter, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayAdapter converts the array into a AbstractList (List) which cannot be modified. Use an ArrayList instead using an array while initializing the ArrayAdapter.

```
String[] data = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k" };

    ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    GridView gvMain;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smena);

        lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));        
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.title_bar, R.id.editText1,lst);

        gvMain = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                ButtonOn(1);
            }
        });
    }

    public void ButtonOn(int Art) {
        lst.add("1");       
        gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This Code   

 String[] items = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};



            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

                    gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

(or)

gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.cust,  R.id.textView1, items));

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error is the LogCat showing...

If its showing you a 'null pointer exception' or 'Unable to start activity' then you should try inflating all the items in a single activity or else intent the data properly to your activity and display the GridView in a new activity.

hope you understand my idea. And more importantly it is not suggested to use Activities as contents of Activity because they consume more memory. I know there are many tutorials which follow the same but hide the drawback.